# R package for calculating partial coefficient of determination?

Tags: r, asbio

Anyone know of an R package for calculating partial R^2 in multiple regression?  I've tried the command partial.R2 from package asbio, but it is giving error messages even with the example from supplied documentation.

Many thanks.

Comment: Could [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/r-implementation-of-coefficient-of-partial-determination) be useful for you?

Comment: I've found out that command lm.sumSquares from package lmSupport provides by partial and semipartial correlations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that command lm.sumSquares from package lmSupport provides by partial and semipartial correlations.

Answer (score 2):

Data from  'Applied Linear Statistical Models' by John Neter, Michael H Kutner, William Wasserman, Christopher J. Nachtsheim

Section 7.4 in page 274:

```
# body fat example from Neter et al.  via rhelp archives:

bf.dat <- read.table(text="x1 x2 x3 y
1 19.5 43.1 29.1 11.9
2 24.7 49.8 28.2 22.8
3 30.7 51.9 37.0 18.7
4 29.8 54.3 31.1 20.1
5 19.1 42.2 30.9 12.9
6 25.6 53.9 23.7 21.7
7 31.4 58.5 27.6 27.1
8 27.9 52.1 30.6 25.4
9 22.1 49.9 23.2 21.3
10 25.5 53.5 24.8 19.3
11 31.1 56.6 30.0 25.4
12 30.4 56.7 28.3 27.2
13 18.7 46.5 23.0 11.7
14 19.7 44.2 28.6 17.8
15 14.6 42.7 21.3 12.8
16 29.5 54.4 30.1 23.9
17 27.7 55.3 25.7 22.6
18 30.2 58.6 24.6 25.4
19 22.7 48.2 27.1 14.8
20 25.2 51.0 27.5 21.1 ", header=TRUE)

library(rms)  # will also load Hmisc
fit <- ols(y ~ x1 + x2, data=bf.dat) 

plt <- plot(anova(fit), what='partial R2')
plt
#         x2          x1 
#0.066955220 0.007010427
```